# Is there a script to collect download links from a website?

Tags: python, web, automation, python-requests, html-select

There's a website which contains a lot of apps and programs I usually use, but everytime I want to upgrade the programs I have to visit the respective page of each program on the website and collect the download links individually (I don't download the apps directly as I first upload them to a Telegram channel using a bot to keep track of the versions.) . Is there a Python script that can collect the download links and return them to me in a text file? I looked into Requests library for Python but I'm not sure how to use it since I'm talking about 70-80 different files with their own pages and different files names each time since when the version number increases the file name changes as in this example : *App v.1.2.apk => App v.1.3.apk*
Oh and how can I compare the text file produced by the script to it's older version and only get the DL link to the apps that have a new version?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/get-links-from-webpage/ 
The first thing that popped up when i googled

Comment: Thank You! That was exactly what I needed. :)